# Sending spanish characters in form submission

Tags: character-encoding, portlet, websphere-portal, jsr286, spring-portlet-mvc

I'm building Portlets using Spring Portlet MVC 3.02 and deploying them on WebSphere Portal V7. I have a form submission where one combo box requires to sent an Spanish character. Something like this:

```
<form:select id="${ns}imTheField" path="imTheField" cssStyle="width:120px;">
    <option value="AtTheEndTheresASpanishCharacterÑ">
        AtTheEndTheresASpanishCharacterÑ
    </option>                                                   
</form:select>
```

The "Ñ" character looks nice in the Screen. That combo value maps to the command attribute `imTheField` by Spring Binding process. After form submission and in the handler method, this is what I get when I log that command attribute:

```
theCommand.getImTheField: AtTheEndTheresASpanishCharacterÃ
```

Which is not the character that came from the form. This is getting me trouble as when there are errors in form submission I have to show the form again with the previous values, which now I don't have because of that issue.

Any ideas? This is what I get from Chrome debugging at form submission:

```
Request Headers
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:es

Form Data
imTheField:AtTheEndTheresASpanishCharacterÑ

Response Headers
Content-Language:es
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Note that the field `imTheField` looks nicely formatted. Maybe is an issue with the `Accept-Charset` request header?

Answer (score 0):

see: http://floatingcube.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/special-characters-in-spring-mvc.html

You may need to use a filter as spring is using ISO-8859-1 rather than UTF-8

Comment: It's  a Portlet application, I don't think Servlet filters apply

Comment: A portlet application is just a variation on a dynamic web application. You can still use filters. For example authentication filters are often used in Websphere Portal for attaching to login and logout events

Comment: ur jsp contains smth like <%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>? if this not helps try implement Action Filter same way as encoding filter above, sources is available on springsource or github